# Can class and id attribute values be same of a html tag?

Tags: html, css

```
<video id="bg-video" class="bg-video"></video>
```

Does this kind of usage cause any problem?

Answer (score 2):

yes it can be same. Just make sure that same id doesn't repeat on different elements.